# Using Blazor WASM, I want to display the dimensions of a Browser window in a <span id=""> when the window opens

Tags: javascript, html, blazor

The solution is built using the Blazor WASM template. I can display the window dimensions when the window is resized ok.

I cannot see how to display the window dimensions when the window opens.

My HTML is in a .razor file.  The contents are:

```
@page "/termsAndConditions"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

    <body class="text-center">
        <span id="windowInnerWidth"></span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span id="windowInnerHeight"></span>

    </body>
        @code {

        }
```

My Javascript is in a .js file.  The file contains the following code that works fine:

```
//Display browser window dimensions as they change
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    document.getElementById("windowInnerWidth").innerHTML = "Width of inner window is: " + window.innerWidth;
});
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    document.getElementById("windowInnerHeight").innerHTML = "Height of inner window is:&nbsp;" + window.innerHeight;
});
```

I've tried many ways to display the window dimensions when the window first opens including:

```
window.addEventListener("open", function () {
    document.getElementById("windowInnerWidth").innerHTML = "Width of inner window is: " + window.innerWidth;
});
```

Nothing works.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: and where is the Blazor part?

Comment: I've amended the example to show the full contents of the .razor page located in the Pages subdirectory of the solution..

Comment: I edited my answer based on your updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  document.getElementById("windowInnerWidth").innerHTML = "Width of inner window is: " + window.innerWidth;
});
```

**Update**
(based on your edited question)

create a new function in your .js file like this:

```
function windowLoaded() {
  document.getElementById("windowInnerWidth").innerHTML = "Width of inner window is: " + window.innerWidth;
}
```

and add this to your .razor file:

```
@code {
  protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
  {
    jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("windowLoaded");
    return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Saleh.  Unfortunately that doesn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: makes a function that return the values:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0, then override OnAfterRenderAsync: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#after-component-render , call the function and show the values

Comment: Thanks Saleh for your example.  I spent a day trying to solve this.
Thanks also to Eliseo for pointing me to the doco.